# String was not recognized as a valid date - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, ssis, date-conversion

In my SSIS project I have a date variable of type [DT_DATE]

I'm trying to convert rows which contains a string (a date and a time)

The format of the string looks like this: `20151107 19:32:23`
I want to convert this into a `datetime` format before I insert it into my db.

My script looks like this:

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

        Dim tempDate As String = Row.calldate

        Row.newcalldate = Date.ParseExact(tempDate, "yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)


    End Sub
```

I end up with the error: `String was not recognized as a valid date`

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What is the value for tempDate when you get this error?

Comment: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @KenTucker I'm not very experienced with SSIS, so I'm not sure. I'm trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the format string `hh` stands for the hour using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.
So if you want to parse a time expressed in 24-hour clock you need to use `HH`

```
Row.newcalldate = Date.ParseExact(tempDate, "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you som much!